# Function to DELETE rows taking the parameters in sql query

Tags: function, plpgsql, sql-delete, dynamic-sql, identifier

I want create a function which removes rows and returns true if there are no errors:

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION s_grnplm_tt.sp_del_stts_cd(num text, package_name text, stts_cd text)
      returns bool
      LANGUAGE plpgsql as 
$func$ 
BEGIN
         EXECUTE 
     'delete FROM s_grnplm_'||num||'tt.log_copy d WHERE d.package_name =' ||package_name|| ' and d.stts_cd = $1'
      
      using stts_cd;
      return true;
end;
$func$;
```

I'm calling a function: select s_grnplm_tt.sp_del_stts_cd('089', '0202_20232211_2434', 'U')

but I get an error:  SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "_20232211_2434"Where: PL/pgSQL function sp_del_stts_cd(text,text,text) line 3 at EXECUTE statement

Answer (score 0):

First, you should to read some about SQL injection issue. You never to pass string variables to SQL just by append `||` operator. You should to sanitize string values before. It can be done by usage function `format` and related placeholders or by using functions `quote_ident` and `quote_literal`.

Second, when you have problem with dynamic SQL (`EXECUTE`) statement, then you should to use `RAISE NOTICE` statement and display executed SQL statement. Then the issue is clean:

```
delete FROM s_grnplm_089tt.log_copy d WHERE d.package_name =0202_20232211_2434 and d.stts_cd = $1
```

You are missing apostrophes in predicate `d.package_name =0202_20232211_2434`.

Your function can be rewritten to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION s_grnplm_tt.sp_del_stts_cd(num text,
                                                      package_name text,
                                                      stts_cd text)
      RETURNS void
      LANGUAGE plpgsql as 
$func$ 
DECLARE sqlstr text;
BEGIN
  sqlstr := format('DELETE FROM %I d WHERE d.package_name = %L AND d.stts_cd = $1',
                   's_grnplm_' || num || 'tt.log_copy', package_name);
  RAISE NOTICE '%', sqlstr;
  EXECUTE sqlstr USING stts_cd;
END;
$func$;
```

Now, the query is correct:

```
DELETE FROM "s_grnplm_089tt.log_copy" d WHERE d.package_name = '0202_20232211_2434' AND d.stts_cd = $1
```

The dynamic SQL requires passing only SQL identifiers as strings. Others can be passed binary by usage `USING` clause. So predicate `d.package_name =` should be used similarly to `d.stts_cd =` predicate:

```
BEGIN
  sqlstr := format('DELETE FROM %I d WHERE d.package_name = $1 AND d.stts_cd = $2',
                   's_grnplm_' || num || 'tt.log_copy');
  RAISE NOTICE '%', sqlstr;
  EXECUTE sqlstr USING package_name, stts_cd;
END;
```

Comment: I get an error
relation "s_grnplm_089tt.log_copy" does not exist 
because the schema contains ""

how to remove "" ???

Comment: @JohnStendreen - I don't understand to question - the message is clean - the table used for DELETE statement doesn't exists